# Count of reads for a request in the Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i wish know how i can get statistics information about read/write operations for the app engine datastore.

i have already tried the appstats application but without any result and i don't find exactly the number of the read/write operations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can just find these in the App Engine Admin Page, under Quota Details? It shows the total number of read / write operations per day.

Also found under Billing -> Usage History

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in my Quota details, it give 0% for the number of read operations, i don't know why knowing that my apps is in use?

Comment: The quota detail part should show exact value instead of percent...e.g. I copy from mine's:

Datastore Entity Fetch Ops    23,634  Okay
Datastore Entity Put Ops    20  Okay
Datastore Entity Delete Ops    12  Okay
Datastore Index Write Ops    367  Okay
Datastore Query Ops    132  Okay
Datastore Key Fetch Ops    7,829  Okay
Datastore Id Allocation Ops    0  Okay

Answer (score 0):

Try using appstats for even more detailed info:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats

Comment: I have already used it but i don't find the number of write or read operations in order to optimize my application costs.

Comment: It shows up in the dev_appserver version, I don't know why it doesn't show up on production.